# What is the purpose for a MERGE statement in SQL compared to JOIN statement?

Tags: sql-server, join, merge

Looking for clarification: is the MERGE statement associated more with getting data into SQL Server whereas JOIN statement more associated data that already exist in SQL Server? Sounds like the same function, but wondering what the general use is for each.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I'll explain further.

MERGE (was once going to be called UPSERT) is a way to compare two datasets, say Source and Target.  If a row is in Source but not in Target, it will INSERT the row.  If a row is in both Source and Target but some non-key values are different, it will UPDATE the row in Target.  Merge is commonly used in loading data warehouses.

JOIN is a way to associate two tables together based on key pairs.  For example

```
SELECT s.Name as SchoolName, st.Name as StudentName
FROM School s
   JOIN Student st ON s.id = st.SchoolID
```